# How to Filter Incoming Tweets by Specific Language on Twitte4j?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I inserted the codes below that into one of my programs that search for tweets with a particular keyword. But it says 'Filter Query cannot be resolved to a type' and twitterstream cannot be resolved to a type'. I have the twitter4j 3.0.5 jar file and this seems to be the latest one on their website, so can you please tell how you figured out these codes and how could you implement it?

```
FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
String[] lang = {"en"};
filterQuery.language(lang);
twitterStream.filter(filterQuery);
```

Comment: I imported the package that you mentioned, but I still got an error. It says FilterQuery cannot be resolved to a type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `import twitter4j.*` to your class in order to use the classes in the Twitter4J JAR file.  Also make sure the Twitter4J 3.0.5 JAR file is on your project's build path so the Java compiler can find the JAR.

You may want to review the [Using Package Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) Java tutorial if you're unclear on how to use the `import` statement or what it does.